# how to split csv file data in batches?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file, with number of lines is multiples of 16.

After reading, I want iterate and inspect each of 16 rows of data.

```
ex: following file has lines, which is multiple of 2
1 2 4
4 5 6
4 5 7
3 4 7
6 7 1
3 1 8

then I want to divide these lines into 3 tables

1 2 4
4 5 6

4 5 7
3 4 7

6 7 1
3 1 8

and iterate each of these individual table.
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I wonder why someone unvoted my question. Once you know the answer, you know how simple the answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the entire data at once, and just need specific number of rows at a time, you can consider reading the csv file in chunk rather than reading the entire data at once.
Something like this will work:

```
fileName = 'sample.csv'
batchSize = 16
for df in pd.read_csv(fileName, chunksize=batchSize):
     process the chunk..
```

Comment: when I print df inside the for loop, I see decimal numbers on top, like header. Also, three dots ... are printed in the middle for all rows. I wonder why. thank you

Comment: If your csv file  has no header, you can pass header=None, Talking about three dots, that might be the way how pandas displays the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways you can do this. One was is to use `numpy` to create the groupings and then use `groupby` to perform the iteration.

```
print(df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  4
1  4  5  6
2  4  5  7
3  3  4  7
4  6  7  1
5  3  1  8

groups = np.arange(len(df)) // 2
for idx, subset in df.groupby(groups):
    print(subset)
    print("-" * 10)

# prints:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  4
1  4  5  6
----------
   a  b  c
2  4  5  7
3  3  4  7
----------
   a  b  c
4  6  7  1
5  3  1  8
----------
```

Comment: this works too but @ThePyGuy code is much simpler. Thank you